# Spring Security and Oauth2 misunderstanding

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-rest

I am currently working on a Spring Boot application and I have the task to do the security of the application. They suggested to use OAuth2 token authentification even thought in other applications I manage to create the security with other spring security tutorial.
This are created based on tutorials I found on different sources:

```
public class OAuthPermissionConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter 

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/pim/oauth/token").permitAll().and().formLogin()
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/webjars/**",
            "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/swagger-resources/configuration/security").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}





 public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider 

@Autowired
private ADService adService;

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
@Transactional
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
    try {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        User user = userService.getUserByUsername(username);
        userService.isUserAllowedToUseTheApplication(user);
        if (adService.isUserNearlyBlockedInAD(user)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(CustomMessages.TOO_MANY_LOGIN_FAILED);
        } else {
            adService.login(username, password);
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> userAuthority = user.getRoles().stream()
                .map(p -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(p.getId())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new LoginToken(user, password, userAuthority);
    } catch (NoSuchDatabaseEntryException | NullArgumentException | NamingException | EmptyUserRolesException e) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException(CustomMessages.INVALID_CREDENTIALS + " or " + CustomMessages.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}





@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}




public class OAuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter 

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Bean
public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
    return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer());
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

    clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("pfjA@Dmin")
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("4gM~$laY{gnfShpa%8Pcjwcz-J.NVS"))
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(UTILS.convertMinutesToSeconds(1440))
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .resourceIds("oauth2-resource");
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
    security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()").allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
}
```

When testing the login, I use postman with this parameters :

http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password

Headers: Basic btoa(pfjA@Dmin,4gM~$laY{gnfShpa%8Pcjwcz-J.NVS)

Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body: form-data -> username and pass
that should be a valid user credentials from the database. 
And the user will respond if the credentials are correct

"access_token": "f0dd6eee-7a64-4079-bb1e-e2cbcca6d7bf",

"token_type": "bearer",

"expires_in": 86399,

"scope": "read write trust"

Now I have to use this token for all the other requests otherwise I dont have any permision to use the application.

My question: Is this other version of Spring Security or what? I read about OAuth2 authentication but I read that an application can have BOTH Spring Security and OAuth2. Can someone please explain me if there is something wrong with the way we decided to implement the app security?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If those are real access credentials then I strongly suggest you redact them (blank them out) to stop other people gaining access to the service in your name.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Most people use OAuth just for authentication and they store authorization details in their local databases. In case of bearer token, you also have userInfoURI to pull information about the user.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can think it's a different version of spring security,it replaces some strategies of standard spring security,such as the authorization checking of requests.

Comment: Welcome to the site. To make your answer more useful, could you elaborate on how Spring security differs from OAuth2?